# Symfony2 env specific robots.txt

Tags: php, symfony, robots.txt

i`m wondering is there a Symfony2 way to have env specific robots.txt file.
When the robots.txt file is in the web(root) directory it is the same for all env.
The only way that i know to do this is to remove the file from the web directory and use env specific routing files to define routes for the robots file and create a function in the controllers to retvrieve the file.

So is there a Symfony2 way to have env specific robots.txt file in a more "cool" way.

Thank you for the time.
Best Regards,
Georgi.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `FrameworkBundle:Template:template` controller to render a twig file based on the environment:

In your routing YML file:

```
acme_robots:
    path: /robots.txt
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Template:template
        template: AcmeBundle:Static:robots_%kernel.environment%.txt.twig
```

Comment: Do not forget to remove original web/robots.txt file to get symfony routing take control

Comment: You could add `_format: txt` to the `defaults` in order to serve it as `text/plain`, rather than `text/html`.

Answer (score 2):

Previous answer is pretty good, but have one problem. Robots.txt will be returned with `Content-type: text/html`.

To return `robots.txt` with `Content-type: text/plain` we need to do next things.

`routing.yml`:

```
app_robots:
    pattern: /robots.txt
    defaults:
        _controller: AppBundle:Static:robots
        # template: AppBundle:Static:robots_%kernel.environment%.txt.twig
```

`src/AppBundle/Controller/StaticController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

/**
 * StaticController controller.
 */
class StaticController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Displays robots.txt.
     */
    public function robotsAction($template = null)
    {
        $response = new Response();
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

        return $this->render($template ?: sprintf(
            "AppBundle:Static:robots_%s.txt.twig",
            $this->container->getParameter('kernel.environment')
        ), array(), $response);
    }
}
```

`AppBundle/Resources/views/Static/robots_prod.txt.twig`:

```
# Production robots.txt

User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

`AppBundle/Resources/views/Static/robots_staging.txt.twig`:

```
# Staging robots.txt

User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Answer (score 0):

The [RobotsBundle](https://github.com/fourlabsldn/RobotsBundle) allows to prevent indexing of your test / dev environment via configuration variable. Simply add this to your config_test.yml / config_dev.yml:

```yaml
four_labs_robots:
    block_all: true
```

It will then add the [X-Robots-Tag: none HTTP header](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag#valid-indexing--serving-directives) to all responses.